# How to convert file .DEX (Dexis image file) to jpg image format using c#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I writing a program that it can read .Dex file (Dexis X-ray image file) and convert it to jpg image. but i can't find out how to decode it. 
i use this code to read and convert but the image is corrupt.

**Read Image:**

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(string IMG_PATH)
    {
        byte[] img = null;
        try
        {
            FileStream IM_STREAM = new FileStream(IMG_PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader IM_BNR = new BinaryReader(IM_STREAM);
            img = IM_BNR.ReadBytes((int)IM_STREAM.Length);
            IM_BNR.Close();
            IM_STREAM.Close();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter("LOG.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8);
            swr.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            swr.Close();
        }
        return img;
    }
```

**Convert Image:**

```
public static void SaveToFile(string path, byte[] b)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

        img.Save(path + "\\exam.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        img.Dispose();
    }
```

The image before convert (.Dex, size 800x600px) -> after convert (.jpg, size 80x60). plz help me.

Comment: You need to know the format of a .dex file and write a decoding function as per the filespec. Do you have info on the file format?

Comment: Thank for the answer, i do not have any info about it, so i post this question here.

Comment: This is not really the place to inquire about that sort of thing. You may get lucky and someone who knows may see this post, but don't count on it. You may be better off contacting some vendors who write the files, assuming the format isn't proprietary, or inquiring on some more appropriate forums.

Answer (score 1):

.dex is a semi-proprietary format.  Using standard image decoding libraries the result you are seeing is the best you can do.  If you are looking for a paid solution I know of a team that is currently working on a web services API for this but it hasn't been released publicly yet.  If you'd be interested in being an early tester I can put you in touch.

Comment: I'm interested, can you share a link to this service?